# How to change the default HTML edit program from MS Word to Netbeans in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, html-files

I am trying to change the default HTML editor program from MS Word to Netbeans, however, I am unable to change the default edit command of Windows using the Windows file options

I already did

- Searched how to chance the edit command of other files, and trying to adapt it for html, no luck, the registery keys were missing at my system
- Tried to edit the default programs, this, only chanced the double click behavor, but I wanting to chance the right click and then edit behavor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default program to open that file type by right-clicking on one, selecting "Open with..." and then "Choose default program..."